# Undefined reference to another class?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I'm using a class within a class and I'm getting errors, I think it's a linking problem. I get "undefined reference to 'Node::setlink()', 'Node::getlink()', and etc. It's all the node functions I used in linked_list.cpp that are the problem.

For example, linked_list.cpp:(.text+0x9de): undefined reference to 
`Node::getlink()'

Linked_list.cpp

```
#include "linked_list.hpp"
#include "node.hpp"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//default constructor
Linked_list::Linked_list(void)
{
    head = new Node();
    tail = new Node();
    head->setlink(NULL);
    tail->setlink(NULL);
    cnt = 0;    
}

//constructor
Linked_list::Linked_list(data x)
{
    head = new Node();
    tail = new Node();
    Node *newnode = new Node(x);
    head->setlink(newnode);
    newnode->setlink(tail); 
    cnt++;      
}

//class function
void Linked_list::insert_node(data x)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node(x);
    Node *prev = new Node();
    Node *curr = new Node();

if (head == NULL)
{

    newNode->setlink(tail);
    head->setlink(newNode); 
}
else if (head != NULL)
{
    prev->setlink(head);
    curr->setlink(head->getlink());
while(curr->getlink() != NULL || newNode->getupc() <= curr->getupc())
{
    prev->setlink(curr);
    curr->setlink(curr->getlink());
}
    prev->setlink(newNode);
    newNode->setlink(curr);
}
    cnt++;
}
//Class function
void Linked_list::delete_node(int u)
{
    char choice;
    data temp;
    Node *newNode = new Node();
    Node *prev = new Node();
    Node *curr = new Node();
if (head == NULL)
{
    delete newNode;
    delete prev;
    delete curr;
}
else if (head != NULL)
{
    prev->setlink(head);
    curr->setlink(head->getlink());
while (curr->getlink() != NULL || curr->getupc() != u )
{
    prev->setlink(curr);
    curr->setlink(curr->getlink());
}
    temp = curr->get_structure();
    cout << temp.UPC << setw(15) << temp.desc << setw(15) << "$" << temp.cost << setw(15) << "Aisle: " << temp.aisle << endl;
    prev->setlink(curr->getlink());
    cout << "Are you sure you want to delete?\n";
    cin >> choice;
if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')
{
    delete curr;
    cnt--;
}
else
{
    choice = 'n';
}
}
}

//Class function
void Linked_list::traverse()
{
    data temp;
    Node *curr = new Node();
if (head == NULL)
{
    delete curr;    
    cout << "The list is empty!\n";     
}
else
{
    curr->setlink(head->getlink());
while(curr->getlink() != NULL)
{
    temp = curr->get_structure();
    cout << temp.UPC << setw(15) << temp.desc << setw(15) << "$" << temp.cost << setw(15) << "Aisle: " << temp.aisle << endl;
}
}
}

void Linked_list::retrieve_node(int u)
{
    data temp;
    Node *x;
    x = new Node();
if (head == NULL)
{
    delete x;   
}   

else if (head != NULL)
{
    x->setlink(head->getlink());

while (x->getlink() != NULL || x->getupc() != u)
{
    x->setlink(x->getlink());
}   
    temp = x->get_structure();
    cout << temp.UPC << setw(15) << temp.desc << setw(15) << "$" << temp.cost << setw(15) << "Aisle: " << temp.aisle << endl;
}
}

void Linked_list::check_empty()
{
if (head != NULL)
{
    cout << "The list is empty.\n";

}   
else
{
    cout << "The list is not empty.\n"; 
}
}
```

linked_list.hpp

```
#include "node.hpp"
#ifndef linked_list_hpp
#define linked_list_hpp

class Linked_list
{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int cnt;
public:
    //default constructor creates empty linked list
    Linked_list(void);

    //Constructor that creates first node with values
    Linked_list(data x);

    //Inserts node at correct spot
    void insert_node(data x);

    //deletes specific node
    void delete_node(int u);

    //goes through whole list and prints out
    void traverse(void);

    //returns specific node
    void retrieve_node(int u);

    //checks if list is empty
    void check_empty();


    return_number();    

};
#endif
```

node.hpp

```
#ifndef node_hpp
#define node_hpp
#include "node.hpp"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct data
{
    int UPC;
    string desc;    
    int quantity;
    double cost;
    int aisle;  
};

class Node
{
    data item;
    Node *link;

public:
    Node(void);
    Node(data x);
    void setlink(Node *ptr);
    Node* getlink();
    int getupc();
    data get_structure();
    bool compare_item(string i);
    double processdata();
};
#endif
```

node.cpp

```
#include "node.hpp"

Node::Node(void)
{
    link = NULL;    
}

Node::Node(data x)
{
    item = x;   
}

void Node::setlink(Node *ptr)
{
    link = ptr;
}

Node* Node::getlink()
{
    return link;    
}

int Node::getupc()
{
    return item.UPC;
}

data Node::get_structure()
{
return item;
}

bool Node::compare_item(string i)
{
if(i==item.desc)
{
    return true;
} 
else
{
    return false;
}
}

double Node::processdata()
{
    return item.cost*item.quantity;
}
```

main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.cpp"
#include "linked_list.cpp"
using namespace std;

void fromfile(Linked_list &x);
void tofile(Linked_list &x);

int main(void)
{
Linked_list ll;
int x, y;
data a;
do
{
cout << "1.Add a grocery item\n" ;
cout << "2.Delete an item\n";
cout << "3.Retrieve an item\n";  
cout << "4.Traverse the list forwards and print out all of the items\n";
cout << "5. Exit the program.\n";
cin >> x;

switch(x)
{
case 1:
cout << "Enter UPC code\n";
cin >> a.UPC;
cout << "Enter description(name of item)\n";
cin >> a.desc;
cout << "Enter quantity\n";
cin >> a.quantity;
cout << "Enter cost\n";
cin >> a.cost;
cout << "Enter aisle\n";
cin >>a.aisle;
ll.insert_node(a);

case 2:
cout << "Enter UPC of item you'd like to delete.\n";
cin >> y;
ll.delete_node(y);

case 3:
cout << "Enter UPC code.\n";
cin >> y;
ll.retrieve_node(y);

case 4:
ll.traverse();

case 5:
cout << "Bye!\n";

default:
cout << "Wrong choice, try again!\n";   
}   
}while (x != 5);

return 0;
}
```

Please help me out, this is due in 2 hours. I think I got it running somehow for a while and after the code performs in main, it just stop creating output after it reaches a linked_list function. Then, I can't enter anything afterwards.

The only thing not compiling is the linked_list.cpp, and I get a winmain error as well.

Comment: All of the .cpp files need to be compiled.   Then the object files from all of them need to be included in the link.    Failure to do those things will explain your LINKER errors.    If you haven't specifically made those things happen, they won't happen.   Specifically, in your case, node.o is not included in the link (and you possibly also haven't compiled node.cpp)

Comment: @Peter When I try to compile node.cpp, it gives me a undefined reference to winmain error. I don't quite understand what you mean by node.o

Comment: @cout -- Then you chose the wrong type of project to build.  Your build environment thinks you're trying to create a Windows program instead of a console (non-Windows) program.  What build system are you using (IDE)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm using devc++ but my school requires us to turn it in using linux, I haven't tried compiling it via linux yet but I doubt it works if linked_list.cpp doesn't work.

Comment: @cout -- DevC++ is a very old build system.  But even so, make sure that when you created your project, you didn't choose "Windows" or something similar to that.  The `winmain` linker error indicates that the linker is looking for the `Windows` entry point into a C++ program, and not the "normal" entry point, which is `main()`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So you think the problem is that since linked_list.cpp is using from node.cpp and they're both not compiling, it's not working?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the source code.  It has everything to do with the project type you selected when you used DevC++.  Start from the beginning -- you start DevC++, you created a project -- what type of project was it?  Was it a Windows project?  Console project?  COM project?  Some other project type?  Whatever it was, it was incorrect.  You added the source files to this (incorrect) project.  Then you compiled the code, the **compilation** was successful.  The linker is now looking for your call to `winmain`. That is a clear indication you selected the wrong project type.

Comment: I just created a new source file and named my programs .cpp and .hpp and then put them into a folder. Maybe it defaulted them.

Comment: No, don't just do that.  Create an empty *project* first -- this is the part that's missing.  Creating a project should now give you the option of choosing the project type.  Then add files to the project.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay, thank you, will keep that in mind for future programs.